# How to extend Observables.combineLatest() with fourth source?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-java3, rx-kotlin2

Imagine there are two `BehaviourSubject` with Strings:

```
private val subjectLocationA = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("London")
private val subjectLocationB = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("Paris")
```

were I update location each like

```
subjectLocationA.onNext("Denver")
```

Then I have a enum class

```
@Serializable
enum class ActiveLocationList(@StringRes val value: Int) {
    ALL_LOCATION("all"),
    MY_FAVLOCATION("favorites")
}
```

used in a Observable:

```
val settingsActiveLocationList: Observable<ActiveLocationList>
```

I combine the above `Subjects` and `Observables` via `combineLatest()`:

```
Observables.combineLatest(
            subjectLocationA,
            subjectLocationB,
            settingsActiveLocationList,
        ).switchMap { (locationA, locationB, activeLocationList) ->
            //..
            }
```

Now I would like to extend a third location subject `subjectLocationC` according to above example. But I am about to extend the combineLatest:

```
Observables.combineLatest(
            subjectLocationA,
            subjectLocationB,
            subjectLocationC,
            settingsActiveLocationList,
        ).switchMap { (locationA, locationB, locationC, activeLocationList) ->
        //..
```

IDE complains with

> Type mismatch.

> Required: (TypeVariable(T1), TypeVariable(T2), TypeVariable(T3)) → TypeVariable(R)

> Found: Observable

and

> Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

According to the `Observables` implementation says amongst others

```
fun <T1 : Any, T2 : Any, T3 : Any> combineLatest
```

and

```
inline fun <T1 : Any, T2 : Any, T3 : Any, T4 : Any, R : Any> combineLatest
```

but nothing in between?! I think I would need

```
fun <T1 : Any, T2 : Any, T3 : Any, T4 : Any> combineLatest
```

or am I wrong? Is there a workaround maybe? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have a library for it, but Stack Overflow doesn't like links, so I use the following code, you can just copy-paste it

```
data class Tuple4<A, B, C, D>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple4[$first, $second, $third, $fourth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple5<A, B, C, D, E>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple5[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple6<A, B, C, D, E, F>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple6[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple7<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple7[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh]"
    }
}

data class Tuple8<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple8[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple9<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple9[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple10<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple10[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple11<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple11[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh]"
    }
}

data class Tuple12<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K,
    val twelfth: L
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple12[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh, $twelfth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple13<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K,
    val twelfth: L,
    val thirteenth: M
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple13[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh, $twelfth, $thirteenth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple14<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K,
    val twelfth: L,
    val thirteenth: M,
    val fourteenth: N
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple14[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh, $twelfth, $thirteenth, $fourteenth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple15<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K,
    val twelfth: L,
    val thirteenth: M,
    val fourteenth: N,
    val fifteenth: O
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple15[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh, $twelfth, $thirteenth, $fourteenth, $fifteenth]"
    }
}

data class Tuple16<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P>(
    val first: A,
    val second: B,
    val third: C,
    val fourth: D,
    val fifth: E,
    val sixth: F,
    val seventh: G,
    val eighth: H,
    val ninth: I,
    val tenth: J,
    val eleventh: K,
    val twelfth: L,
    val thirteenth: M,
    val fourteenth: N,
    val fifteenth: O,
    val sixteenth: P
) : Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tuple16[$first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh, $twelfth, $thirteenth, $fourteenth, $fifteenth, $sixteenth]"
    }
}

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>): Flowable<Pair<T1, T2>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    BiFunction<T1, T2, Pair<T1, T2>> { t1, t2 -> t1 to t2 }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>): Flowable<Triple<T1, T2, T3>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    Function3<T1, T2, T3, Triple<T1, T2, T3>> { t1, t2, t3 -> Triple(t1, t2, t3) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>): Flowable<Tuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    Function4<T1, T2, T3, T4, Tuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>> { t1, t2, t3, t4 -> Tuple4(t1, t2, t3, t4) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>): Flowable<Tuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    Function5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Tuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 -> Tuple5(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>): Flowable<Tuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    Function6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, Tuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 -> Tuple6(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>): Flowable<Tuple7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    Function7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7 -> Tuple7(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>): Flowable<Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    Function8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8 -> Tuple8(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>): Flowable<Tuple9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>> = Flowable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    Function9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, Tuple9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9 -> Tuple9(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>): Flowable<Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple10(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>): Flowable<Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple11(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>, f12: Flowable<T12>): Flowable<Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple12(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>, f12: Flowable<T12>, f13: Flowable<T13>): Flowable<Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple13(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>, f12: Flowable<T12>, f13: Flowable<T13>, f14: Flowable<T14>): Flowable<Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13, 
    f14), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple14(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any, T15: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>, f12: Flowable<T12>, f13: Flowable<T13>, f14: Flowable<T14>, f15: Flowable<T15>): Flowable<Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13,
    f14, 
    f15), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple15(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14, t[14] as T15)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any, T15: Any, T16: Any> combineTuple(f1: Flowable<T1>, f2: Flowable<T2>, f3: Flowable<T3>, f4: Flowable<T4>, f5: Flowable<T5>, f6: Flowable<T6>, f7: Flowable<T7>, f8: Flowable<T8>, f9: Flowable<T9>, f10: Flowable<T10>, f11: Flowable<T11>, f12: Flowable<T12>, f13: Flowable<T13>, f14: Flowable<T14>, f15: Flowable<T15>, f16: Flowable<T16>): Flowable<Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>> = Flowable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13,
    f14,
    f15,
    f16), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple16(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14, t[14] as T15, t[15] as T16)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>): Observable<Pair<T1, T2>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    BiFunction<T1, T2, Pair<T1, T2>> { t1, t2 -> t1 to t2 }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>): Observable<Triple<T1, T2, T3>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    Function3<T1, T2, T3, Triple<T1, T2, T3>> { t1, t2, t3 -> Triple(t1, t2, t3) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>): Observable<Tuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    Function4<T1, T2, T3, T4, Tuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>> { t1, t2, t3, t4 -> Tuple4(t1, t2, t3, t4) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>): Observable<Tuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    Function5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Tuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 -> Tuple5(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>): Observable<Tuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    Function6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, Tuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 -> Tuple6(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>): Observable<Tuple7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    Function7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7 -> Tuple7(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>): Observable<Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    Function8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8 -> Tuple8(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>): Observable<Tuple9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>> = Observable.combineLatest(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    Function9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, Tuple9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9 -> Tuple9(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9) }
)

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>): Observable<Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple10(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>): Observable<Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple11<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple11(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>, f12: Observable<T12>): Observable<Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple12<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple12(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>, f12: Observable<T12>, f13: Observable<T13>): Observable<Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple13<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple13(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>, f12: Observable<T12>, f13: Observable<T13>, f14: Observable<T14>): Observable<Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13,
    f14), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple14<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple14(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any, T15: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>, f12: Observable<T12>, f13: Observable<T13>, f14: Observable<T14>, f15: Observable<T15>): Observable<Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13,
    f14,
    f15), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple15<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple15(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14, t[14] as T15)
    }
})

fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, T3: Any, T4: Any, T5: Any, T6: Any, T7: Any, T8: Any, T9: Any, T10: Any, T11: Any, T12: Any, T13: Any, T14: Any, T15: Any, T16: Any> combineTuple(f1: Observable<T1>, f2: Observable<T2>, f3: Observable<T3>, f4: Observable<T4>, f5: Observable<T5>, f6: Observable<T6>, f7: Observable<T7>, f8: Observable<T8>, f9: Observable<T9>, f10: Observable<T10>, f11: Observable<T11>, f12: Observable<T12>, f13: Observable<T13>, f14: Observable<T14>, f15: Observable<T15>, f16: Observable<T16>): Observable<Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11,
    f12,
    f13,
    f14,
    f15,
    f16), object : Function<Array<*>, Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>> {
    override fun apply(t: Array<*>): Tuple16<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return Tuple16(t[0] as T1, t[1] as T2, t[2] as T3, t[3] as T4, t[4] as T5, t[5] as T6, t[6] as T7, t[7] as T8, t[8] as T9, t[9] as T10, t[10] as T11, t[11] as T12, t[12] as T13, t[13] as T14, t[14] as T15, t[15] as T16)
    }
})
```